# How can I capture the time in a variable in python?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a Dag which executes 3 different sql inserting data.
But there is problem with capturing timestamp in a variable.
I want to insert the same time in 3 different tables.

The code is like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
start_task_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

with DAG("inform_status",
         schedule_interval="55 17 * * 1-5",
         start_date=days_ago(1),
         catchup=False,
         tags=["Inform Status"]) as dag:

create_report_1 = PostgresOperator(
         task_id='create_report_1',
         postgres_conn_id='inform_status',
         sql=f"""
            INSERT into table1 (created_date, dbid)
            SELECT '{start_task_time}'::timestamp with time zone, dbid
            FROM pg_catalog.gp_segment_configuration;
         """
         )
create_report_2 = PostgresOperator(
         task_id='create_report_2',
         postgres_conn_id='inform_status',
         sql=f"""
            INSERT into table2 (created_date, dbid)
            SELECT '{start_task_time}'::timestamp with time zone, dbid
            FROM pg_catalog.gp_segment_configuration;
         """
         )
```

....
Output of start_task_time in create_report_1 is 2023-09-07 18:00:58.739 +0300,
in create_report_2 is 2023-09-07 18:00:58.759 +0300.

They're not the same.

How can solve this problem?

Comment: I observed them in my DB after inserting

Comment: can you add print(start_task_time) before each db call? are they the same or different?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that datetime.now() is being called each time. I would try one thing.

Try datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') as this might be happening as the variable within the query might be calling the datetime.now each time